# How to remove a button embedded in the window? (Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I created a play button for a game and I would like to remove it when we click on it.

However, I have it in the window with canvas.create_window, so I can not delete it with "pack_forget".

Do you have any idea how to remove it?

```
bouton_play=PhotoImage(file="bouton_play.gif")
Jouer=Button(fenetre,image=bouton_play,relief=FLAT,borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,command=debut)
canvas.create_window(144,450,window=Jouer)
```

Comment: if you are certain that you would not use the button in the future, you can always delete the `create_window` item from the canvas

Comment: Yes but after I want to create, with canvas create_window, a button replay so is this a problem?

Comment: the easiest solution is to create a **frame** on the canvas using `create_window`, and use all your widgets normally.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about this, would you have an example of using this solution?

Comment: Save the ID of the window, like `button = canvas.create_window(...)`.  Then inside the button command function, execute `canvas.delete(button)` to remove the button.

Comment: It does not correspond to my situation :)  I would like the button to be completely removed from the window

Comment: It does remove the window containing the button.

Answer (score 2):

Once you insert the button in the canvas, you must treat it like a canvas element, and use `canvas.delete(tag_or_id)` instead of `widget.geometry_manager_forget()`

```
import tkinter as tk

def debut():
    print('debut')
    canvas.delete(btnw)  # <-- this removes the window containing the button

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
btn = Button(root, text='jouer', command=debut)
btnw = canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=btn)  # <- this is the canvas element to delete from the canvas 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code. On clicking the button, it should disappear.

```
import tkinter as Tk

def disappear():
    but.grid_forget()

root = Tk.Tk()

canvas = Tk.Canvas(root, bg = 'black', width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

frame = Tk.Frame(bg = 'red')
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = frame, anchor = Tk.NW)

but = Tk.Button(frame, text = 'Disappear', command = disappear)
but.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately it does not fit my situation

Comment: The button will go away, but the frame widget will still be on the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes. I was just giving him an example of how to use frames on canvas. He doesn't specify his problem well, as can be seen from the comment chain (on the question).